# How will you extract the word "0U47NN4XMD8V "?

Tags: java, string, extract

How will you extract the word "0U47NN4XMD8V " from a paragraph "Changes for update of Product 0U47NN4XMD8V has been submitted, it may take upto 1 hour for these changes to be reflected. Please check from Product Search Page after some time" using java code ?

Comment: pinch of regex, dash of code. mix thoroughly and bake for 10-20 years in brain.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have already tried? Anything to show what kind of systems you are working with?

Comment: Will the sentence and 'word' be the exact same every time? If so you can just use `substring()` with the indices of the 'word'.

Comment: No the word will not be same every time it will change

Comment: Every time I need to extract the sixth  word from the message

Comment: gave you two different scenarios, not sure what you want tbh

Comment: The xpath for the paragraph id //*[@id='ng-app']/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is your sentence you want to extract the code from
String sentence = "Changes for update of product 0U47NN4XMD8V has been submitted,it may take up to 1 hour for these changes to be reflected";

//This is an array of strings, which is your sentence split by every space,
//hence (" "), it can be (",") or anything else you wanna split by. 
//This array has a size of 22 since you can split your sentence into 22 parts for 
//every space and it starts at 0 since its Java
String [] parts = sentence.split(" ");

//We want the 6th element so we assign a string our 6th element 
//in our array - parts[5] since it is zero based
String extracted = parts[5];

//do stuff
```

Comment: maybe add some length check, if the paragraph happens to be less than 6 words.

Comment: Yea I agree, except I don't know what he really wants, so this is a quick "fix"

Comment: i think this pretty much fits his needs as he added a comment to his original question: "No the word will not be same every time it will change" and "Every time I need to extract the sixth word from the message"

Comment: An explanation of your solution would be appreciated. Please keep in mind that unexperienced users might read your answer in the future.

Comment: please close and select an answer if this is what you're looking for @Kaja Sheriff

Answer (score 0):

```
String code = "0U47NN4XMD8V" // Or a get method where this comes from

String message =  "Changes for update of Product 0U47NN4XMD8V has been submitted,it may take up to 1 hour for these changes to be reflected";

if(message.contains(code)){
    //do something
}
```